# Crash reading list suggestions in image processing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I develop classification and optimization algorithms for living, but have no experience in image processing. Tomorrow (in 12 hours from now) I have a technical job interview in a company that does image analysis (abnormality detection in scanned patterns).

What would you suggest me to read before such an interview? (Please spare the obvious tips such as "you can't learn this in 12 hours", "be yourself", etc)

Comment: is it possible to make this question 'community wiki'?

Comment: Probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, if anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russ' [image processing handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/084931142X) is a good start and can easily be skimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if you have Matlab or not, its documentation is excellent, so you could skim through the imaging toolbox documentation which provide ample [demos](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html) and [examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/exampleindex.html).

For a book, you could look at [Digital Image Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0982085400) by Gonzales.